# Why is grecaptcha.getResponse() empty on Google reCAPTCHA V2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get reCAPTCHA reponse after the reCAPTCHA checkbox is checked. So my code is like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //Trying to get the reCAPTCHA response
    var  sResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    alert(sResponse); //But this is empty
});
```

My HTML is like this:

```
<div class = "g-recaptcha" data-sitekey = "MY_SITE_KEY_HERE"></div>
```

The reCAPTCHA shows up alright but `grecaptcha.getResponse()` returns empty string even after the checkbox is checked. What could be the reasion why `grecaptcha.getResponse()` is empty? Could there be any fix? Nevertheless, I get value for `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` when I submit the same form to PHP directly without JavaScript.

Comment: my code appears to have started doing this just now, great question why no answer?